# Using Add Symbol As NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

Does anybody know how to get the green add symbol below as NSImage?  I want to place it with the standard cursor over a desktop screenshot.

[image]

I don't find it at CoreServices (/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/).

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you cut it from the image you added to your Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly googled the location of cursers in OS X and found the solution [here](http://einserver.de/blog/resources-for-cursors-in-mac-os-x).
Use Finders Go to Folder function and paste the following path:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors
```

There you will find a bunch of folders, the one you are looking for is the `copy` folder. Inside, you will find the curser as a vector based PDF.